# jquery after keyup event

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery.autocomplete plugin. What i wants is if returned options are greater than 30 then wants to display some message like list is not complete. To handle this i did

```
$('div').ajaxStop(function() {
    if ($(this).find('DIV').length >= 30) {
        $("<div class='autocomplete clsautocomplete' style='background-  color:#ffffb0'>Partial list - keep typing to filter</div>").insertAfter($(this));
    } else {
        $('.test').hide();
    }
});
```

and for next time it gets value form cache so the ajaxStop is not called.

thats why i am trying to check this on keyup event but it is not working.

If some has idea to handle this then please give to me.

Thanks

Comment: Are there any callbacks in the plugin that fire after the list is retrieved?  That way you are not relying on an ajax call.

Comment: Which autocomplete plugin are you using?